VSCode how to jump to an open file whose tab is not visible
In VSCode on my VirtualBox on Win 10, I have six tabs open, but only four tabs are showing. How can I jump to an open file whose tab isn't showing?
Tried Googling and tried finding a sidescroll, like in other apps, but no joy.

Use the Open Editors view - View/Open View/Open Editors.

To jump to a file in VS Code, press Ctrl+P and type the name of the file and press enter, or select from the dropdown that appears.
